# How could I convert an existing SWF file to an SWC for using as a library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

I am new to the ActionScript world and I bumped into a problem that is hard for me. I have an SWF file that contains some classes that I cannot recompile from source but want to use again in a different project. I see that SWC files are containing compiled classes that can be easily reused. My question is how could I convert the existing SWF file to an SWC file so that I can use it as a regular library? Google did not help me.

Comment: You could compile your code to an SWC instead of an SWF!

Comment: @Florent I wrote that I cannot recompile the SWF from source. I even decompiled it and tried to recompile but the decompiler generates uncompilable code.

Comment: Do you mean you neither have the source code nor the FLA?

Comment: None of them. It uses a specific version of the Facebook API compiled in that was fixed for the sake of the rest of the program. I have the sources of the rest, but would like to use exactly that fixed Facebook API that is in the SWF.

Comment: Any update? Maybe you could approve an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWC files use ZIP compression, and actually contain a SWF. If you change the file extension from `.swc` to `.zip` you can browse the contents and directory structure. It looks like this:

```
foobar.swc
    -> catalog.xml
    -> library.swf
```

With some reverse engineering, you might be able to create a SWC from a SWF by building the `catalog.xml` file and packing them together in ZIP file.

But that seems rather complex! You could also simply load the external SWF into your own SWF using [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html). All of the classes, symbols, and timelines of the external SWF will then be available. Of course, this creates a run-time dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are not able to recompile your code to an SWC, I suggest you to use a `Loader` if you don't need to access the classes as compile-time.

```
[Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]
public class SWFLibrary extends EventDispatcher
{
    private var loader:Loader;
    private var loaded:Boolean;

    public function SWFLibrary(urlOrBytes:*)
    {
        super();

        loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

        if (urlOrBytes is String) {
            loader.load(new URLRequest(urlOrBytes));
        } else if (urlOrBytes is URLRequest) {
            loader.load(urlOrBytes);
        } else if (urlOrBytes is ByteArray) {
            loader.loadBytes(urlOrBytes);
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentError("Invalid urlOrBytes argument");
        }
    }

    public function getAssetClass(className:String):Class
    {
        if (!loaded) {
            throw new IllegalOperationError("The SWF library isn't loaded");
        }

        return loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(className) as Class;
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        loaded = true;

        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
}
```